# Reading .env for nestjs app with typeorm having custom provider

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I am new to `nestJS` and I want to setup `.env` for existing application & facing issue.

I have custom provider for `appModule` as below,

```
@Module({
    providers: [
      AbcService,
      XyzService,
    ],
    imports: [
      TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
        type: 'mysql',
        host: 'xxxxxxxx',
        port: 3230,
        username: 'xyz',
        password: 'password',
        database: 'xyz-db',
        entities: [__dirname + '/entities/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
        synchronize: true,
        migrationsRun: true,
        logging: true,
      }),
      TypeOrmModule.forFeature([
        Transaction,
        Payment,
      ]),
      
      KafkaModule.forRoot(serviceConfig),
    ],
    exports: [],
    controllers: [ServiceSubscriptionController],
  })
  export class TopicModule { }
```

I have imported it inside `AppModule` as below,

```
  @Module({
    imports: [TopicModule],
    controllers: [AppController],
    providers: [AppService],
  })
  export class AppModule {}
```

I want to keep these stuff inside `.env` and I tried it as per documentation as below,

```
TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
  imports: [ConfigModule.forRoot({
    envFilePath: '.env',
  })],
  useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => {
    return {
        host: configService.get('HOST'),
        type: 'mysql',
        port: 3230,
        username: 'xyz',
        password: 'password',
        database: 'xyz-db',
        entities: [__dirname + '/entities/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
        synchronize: true,
        migrationsRun: true,
        logging: true,
    }
  },
  inject: [ConfigService]
}),
```

I have `.env` at root path with `HOST` key-value pair as below but it read undefined from it.

In `package.json`,

```
    "start": "nest start",
    "start:dev": "nest start --watch",
```

Comment: Have you tried [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv)?

Comment: @SevvyP if this is `@nestjs/config`'s `ConfigModule` `dotenv` is used under the hood. @ray can you share your current code setup? Everything looks fine from what I can see

Comment: used `[ConfigModule.forRoot({ envFilePath: '.env'})]` instead of `[ConfigModule]` as it did not work

Comment: @JayMcDoniel not able to share, added some update in question. I have added two `.env` roor path of project and another one is at root path of custom provider module.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Nest's `ConfigModule` will run `fs.readFileSync(envFilePath)` if you pass a file path to the `forRoot()` method. If you want it to read from the root directory, either remove the `envFilePath` option, or set the full file path, from your user's home directory.

Comment: Initially tried same and did not work so passed `envFilePath`.

Comment: I found solution or missing part (if that is the case) which worked for me. It will be good if you put light on it because `nestjs` is new to me.

Answer (score 0):

I have loaded config in `main.ts` manually as below.

```
import { config } from 'dotenv';

async function bootstrap() {
  //factory method for normal TS app
  await config();
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
```

Now I can access it as,

```
configService.get('HOST') // as provided in question
```

or as `process.env.HOST`

**Note**: I have to use `forRootAsync` instead of `forRoot` to access `process.env`

Comment: If you are using `@nestjs/config` then you shouldn't need to call `config` from `dotenv`